# NodeJS / Multer : How do I insert another pdf file in my schema

Tags: node.js, multer

I can create a new schema, i can update the already pdf file in the schema. but i'm having trouble adding another pdf file on database.
i've tried InsertOne but it adds a new collection schema, and updateOne replaces the file already written. I need to add another pdf file in the same collection.

I searched around almost everywhere i could think of, i cant find out how to do it. please help

Answer (score 0):

Usually how people store files in a database is by storing the path to the file instead of storing the entire file. Generally, you would want to store the file inside a folder in the server directory.